# How to extract some text from an HTML doc using Web::Query

Tags: perl

I'm trying to extract the subject (between the h3 tags) in the following example using Web::Query. Find 'h3' returns the author text, but I want the h3 in the subject class instead. I tried .subject.div.h3 but it returns undef.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Web::Query; # libweb-query-perl
use Data::Dumper;

my $testhtml ='
<html><head></head>
<body>
   <div class="author"
      <div><h3>Neil Watson</h3></div>
   </div>
   <div class="subject">
      <div><h3>@if version_after macro is illogical</h3></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
';

my $parts = Web::Query->new_from_html( $testhtml );
my $subject = $parts->find( 'div.subject.div.h3' )->text;

print "subjectfinal ".Dumper( $subject );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot selector denotes class selections, which is not what you intend for the second div and h3. For these you want descendant. The correct syntax is;

```
my $subject = $parts->find( 'div.subject > div > h3' )->text;

# Which outputs
# subjectfinal $VAR1 = '@if version_after macro is illogical';
```

For more information on CSS selectors which is what Web::Query is loosely based off have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp